# Can't figure out the beginning of my minesweeper

Tags: jframe, minesweeper

I need to make a minesweeper game where in the beginning it must ask for the difficulty (easy, medium or hard). From there the JFrame size must change and the amount of blocks and mines must come in. How do I change the JFrame size if I click on one of the buttons?

Comment: What have you tried? You need to show some example code and why it didn't work for you before we can really help.

Comment: If you call JFrame.pack(), it sets the JFrame to be big enough to hold the components comfortably. This means that all you'd have to do is generate the number of squares you'd need. 

Perhaps each square could be an object that extends JButton?